# How can I determine the scrolling speed of a RecyclerView in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to calculate the scrolling speed of the recyclerview. I want to perform certain actions by understanding whether the user scrolls down the page fast or not.

I found this block of code on StackOverFlow. I suppose this code is for changing the speed of scrolling. I don't want to change, just want to calculate the speed and perform something according to this speed.

```
class CustomLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(
        context,
        orientation,
        reverseLayout
    ) {
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    }

    companion object {
        private const val MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 5f //default is 25f (bigger = slower)
    }

    override fun smoothScrollToPosition(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State?,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val linearSmoothScroller: LinearSmoothScroller =
            object : LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.context) {
                override fun computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition: Int): PointF? {
                    return super.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition)
                }

                protected override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi
                }
            }
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position)
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```kotlin
private var lastScrollTime: Long = 0
private var lastScrollY: Int = 0
private var scrollSpeed: Int = 0

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val timeDelta = currentTime - lastScrollTime
            val distanceDelta = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() - lastScrollY
            scrollSpeed = (distanceDelta / timeDelta * 1000).toInt()
            lastScrollTime = currentTime
            lastScrollY = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
        }
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        if (recyclerView.scrollState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            lastScrollY = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
        }
    }
})
```

try this

lastScrollTime and lastScrollY respectively record the timestamp and scroll distance of the last scroll stop. In the onScrollStateChanged method, if the scroll stops, the scroll time and distance are calculated to obtain the scroll speed. In the onScrolled method, if the scroll has not stopped, the value of lastScrollY is updated.